# php password reset fails

Tags: php, password-encryption

I am upgrading a php login system to use password_hash(). I started with the following test file to generator the hash:

```
$password="aaaaaaaa";
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hash."<br>";

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {echo "Valid";}
else {echo "Invalid";}
```

I then copied and pasted the hash from the screen directly into the db (mysql varchar(255). When logging in I validate with:

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
$passwordIsValid=true;
//echo "VALID PASSWORD";
} else {
$passwordIsValid=false;
//echo "INVALID PASSWORD";
}
```

$hash is the hash value obtained from the db. This validates correctly with the hash that I copied and pasted.

However I have added a lost password script where the user enters their new password this is sent to a second script via AJAX which  hashes the password thus:

```
$password=$_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) 
{//write to db using PDO/prepared statements}
else {
echo "Invalid credentials";
exit();
}
```

When I attempt to login after the password has been changed like this password_valid() returns false everytime. If I go back to copy and paste it then validates correctly.

Can anybody point to where the problem is please?

Comment: Either you're screwing up when inserting the hash into the database, or you're not sending the password you think you're sending via AJAX. We don't know. Also, the `password_verify` immediately after the hash is pretty pointless. If that isn't always `true`, PHP is broken.

Comment: The password_verify was added just to help me debug. I appreciate that  I'm screwing something up the problem is I can't see where tho logic says it must be somewhere in the password reset routine

Comment: Start by inspecting the AJAX request in your browser to ensure you're sending what you think you're sending. `var_dump` the `$password` in PHP to ensure you're hashing what you think you're hashing. `var_dump` the `$hash` and compare with what ends up in your database to ensure that step works correctly. Somewhere along the line you'll notice some discrepancy…

Answer (score 1):

Add a trim to your password.

```
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);
```

and ensure to have the good enctype (ISO, UTF... but everywhere the same).

Comment: Thanx Meloman - When you say to use ISO enc do you mean for the db?

Comment: I say jsute ensure to have the same on php pages, html result pages (with meta tag) and database. I prefer all in UTF-8 everywhere.